# Generating combinations of alphanumeric chars in a certain form

Tags: python

I would like to generate a list

**Required result:** AA0000 -> ZZ9999

I have done the following (Python3)

```
from itertools import *
inputa = product('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', repeat=2)
inputb = product('123467890', repeat=4)
```

I don't think this is the best way to achieve my goal, as it seems to require a few more adjustments to get the result. (It currently only makes all possibilities of each side of the desired string, separated by comma. )
[image: Undesired output]

**Q**. What could i do to achieve the required result?

Comment: What will be the result for `BB1111` ?

Comment: Do you need outputs like `AB0000`, `AC0000` etc as well?

Comment: If I read correctly, this will produce 6,760,000 results.

Comment: @ChrisCharley yes, that is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building on what you've started.

```
from itertools import *
inputa = list(product('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', repeat=2))
inputb = list(product('123467890', repeat=4))

inputa = [''.join(x) for x in inputa]
inputb = [''.join(x) for x in inputb]

output = list(product(inputa,inputb))
output = [''.join(x) for x in output]
```

Output

```
['AA1111',
 'AA1112',
 'AA1113',
 'AA1114',
 'AA1116',
 'AA1117',
 'AA1118',
 'AA1119',
 'AA1110',
 'AA1121',
 'AA1122',
.....
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is another option:

```py
from itertools import product

a = [''.join(_) for _ in product('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', repeat=2)]
n = [f'{_:04d}' for _ in range(10000)]
axn = [''.join(_) for _ in product(a, n)]
```

That will result in something like this:

```py
>>> len(axn)
6760000
>>> axn[0]
'AA0000'
>>> axn[-1]
'ZZ9999'
>>> 'AB1234' in axn
True
>>>
```

Finally, if you are using a Python version prior from 3.6, use this version:

```py
from itertools import product

a = [''.join(_) for _ in product('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', repeat=2)]
n = ['%04d' % _ for _ in range(10000)]
axn = [''.join(_) for _ in product(a, n)]
```